# NFC does not wait other codes

Tags: java, android, nfc

I have following codes. However, the app doesn't start callfunc() before reading the tag. After reading tag, I see filled bar instead of filling bar. Thats why I cant show progress bar, timer doesn't work properly. I have no idea why.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    callfunc();

    //read the tag
}

public void callfunc(){
    //progres bar working with countdown timer
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    enableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    disableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    super.onPause();
}
private void enableForegroundDispatchSystem(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent, 0);
    IntentFilter[] intentFilter = new IntentFilter[]{};
     nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this,pendingIntent,intentFilter,null);
 }
 private void disableForegroundDispatchSystem(){
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: If the omitted code `//read the tag` is for reading the tag, then `callfunc()` will have been called. So either the problem is in the omitted code of `callfunc()`, or your understanding of the code flow is incorrect. Check with the debugger if`callfunc()` is called and show its code.

Comment: @Codo Thank you, I solve my problem with creating two threads. One for callfunc(), other for reading the tag. Interestingly, android gives a priority to NFC reading operations, if i dont use particular thread for it.

Comment: With `enableForegroundDispatch` when a Tag is detected you App gets `Paused` whilst the Tag is read and then `Resumed` with the Intent data paused to the Main thread. You App is not actually doing the reading it is just receiving data from a windowless System App, You might want to look at the `enableReaderMode` API as this is a better API and when a Tag is discovered a new Thread is automatically started to handle it.